# R: I'm trying to apply rollmean(zoo) to a particular column in several dataframes which are in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, mean, zoo

reprod:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(0:9), Y = c(10:19))  
df2 <- data.frame(X = c(0:9), Y = c(10:19))  
df3 <- data.frame(X = c(0:9), Y = c(10:19))

list_of_df <- list(A = df1, B = df2, C = df3)  
list_of_df
```

I'm trying to apply the rollmean function from zoo to every 'Y' column in this list of dataframes.
I've tried lapply with no success, It seems no matter which way i spin it, there is no way to get around specifying the dataframe you want to apply to at some point.

This does one of the dataframes

```
roll_mean <- rollmean(list_of_df$A, 2)
roll_mean
```

obviously this doesn't work:

```
roll_mean1 <- rollmean(list_of_df, 2)
roll_mean1
```

I also tried this:
subset(may not be necessary)

```
Sub1 <- lapply(list_of_df, "[", 2)
roll_mean1 <- rollmean(Sub1, 2)
roll_mean1
```

there doesn't seem to be a way to do it without having to
specify the particular dataframe in the rollmean function

```
lapply(list_of_df), function(x) rollmean(list_of_df, 2))
```

for loop? also no success

```
For (i in list_of_df) {roll_mean1 <- rollmean(Sub1, 2)
    Exp 
}
```

Stating the obvious but I'm very new to coding in general and would appreciate some pointers.
It has occurred to me that even if it did work, the column that has been averaged would be one value longer than the rest of the dataframe; how would I get around that?

Comment: Did you mean this for using `lapply`? `lapply(list_of_df, function(x) rollmean(x, 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question at one point says that it wants to perform the rollmean only on Y and at another point says that this works `roll_mean <- rollmean(list_of_df$A, 2)` but that does *all* columns.

**1)** Assuming that you want to apply `rollmean` to all columns:

Use `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(list_of_df, rollmean, 2)
```

This also works:

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_df)) list_of_df[[i]] <- rollmean(list_of_df[[i]], 2)
```

**2)** If you only want to apply it to the Y column:

```
lapply(list_of_df, transform, Y = rollmean(Y, 2, fill = NA))
```

or

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_df)) {
  list_of_df[[i]]$Y <- rollmean(list_of_df[[i]]$Y, 2, fill = NA)
}
```